JVMTI's jvmtiEventCallbacks.ClassFileLoadHook not hooking "java.lang.Thread"
Using jvmti 11.0.3.7 on Microsoft Windows. The 'ClassFileLoadHook' does not hook "java/lang/Thread". Is "Thread" special in some way? Does the callback happen too late in process startup? Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?
typedef void (JNICALL *jvmtiEventClassFileLoadHook)
    (jvmtiEnv *jvmti_env,
     JNIEnv* jni_env,
     jclass class_being_redefined,
     jobject loader,
     const char* name,
     jobject protection_domain,
     jint class_data_len,
     const unsigned char* class_data,
     jint* new_class_data_len,
     unsigned char** new_class_data);

I watched the 'name's that are hooked. "java/lang/Thread" is not seen. It seems all other classes in the "java.lang" namespace seem to be hooked, but I have no way of proving what other classes (if any) are missing.

Do you see java/lang/Object?

no. Interestingly, I ran the same test on Linux and "java/lang/Thread" and "java/lang/Object" are both hooked. However (on Linux) parameter "jni_env" is null when "java/lang/Thread" is hooked. I also need to understand that as well as I am pretty sure I need "jni_env".

Maybe Class Data Sharing is active in one case but not the other.

So it appears that some callbacks are "informational" and not "functional". Callbacks that happen during the "primordial phase" of JVMTI are informational only, IL rewriting cannot be performed. My conclusion for Windows: since the callback for "java.Lang.Thread" on Windows is not functional, the callback was not issued, probably developer's choice and was intentional.
